# Get output of "getprop | grep" shell command

Tags: java, android, shell, output

I am trying to get output of command "getprop | grep".

Here is my code:

```
    public static void propFinder(String Prop) {
        try {
              Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop | grep "+Prop);
              BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

              StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
              String line;
              while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                log.append(line + "\n");
              }
              Log.e(TAG,log.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
    }
```

I want to find out informations displayed about a specific prop. For example, "init.svc.sdcard".

Here is log output:

```
 11-21 09:16:04.143: I/Choreographer(14514): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 11-21 09:16:05.583: E/PropFinder(14514): grep
```

Forgot to say, if i issue only getprop, i get a good output, but it's incomplete.
Googled around, used every method of issuing a command i've found. All are the same.

I don't know if it helps, but i have roottools library available. (tried using their method, same result ).

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use grep4j for this?

```
public static void propFinder(String Prop) {
        GrepResults lineContainingTheProp = grep(constantExpression(Prop),  on(propertyFileProfile()));
        log.append(lineContainingTheProp);
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't help as i don't want to read from a file. Sorry for the late response.